# mysqldump con parámetros

Tags: mysql

Querida comunidad un cordial saludo para todos y espero se encuentren bien, resulta que estoy tratando de realizar un backup de los dos últimos días para que al momento de restaurar el backup no tarde demasiado ni sature el servidor, este es el código de la consult:

```
mysqldump -u root -p prueba fecha --where="SELECT * from fechas where fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY"
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */
> `idFechas`, `fecha`, `nombres` FROM `fechas` WHERE SELECT idFecha,
> fecha, nombres from fechas where fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY':
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SELECT idFecha, fecha, nombres from fechas where fecha >
> curdate() - INTERVAL 2 ' at line 1 (1064)

Desde ya agradezco vuestra gentil atención.

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro `--where` solo espera la condición y en tu caso le estás pasando una consulta completa.

El comando sería:

```
mysqldump -u root -p prueba fecha --where="fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY"
```

Fíjate que el error te está dando la consulta que está lanzando:

> SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ idFechas, fecha, nombres **FROM fechas
> WHERE SELECT idFecha, fecha, nombres from fechas where fecha >
> curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY'**

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfectamente, al estar buscando en los parametros de mysqldump encontre la opcion "--insert-ignore" necesito que al momento de realizar la importacion de datos ignore los datos duplicados entonces estaria bien asi? "mysqldump -u root -p --insert-ignore prueba fechas --where="fecha > curdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY">dbduralit1.sql"

Comment: En principio si. aunque el ignore lo hará en base a la primary key. Si eso es lo que esperas está correcto. No te olvides marcar la respuesta como vlaida :)